# Making XMLHttpRequest request not timing out?

Tags: javascript, rest, nginx, xmlhttprequest

I have this post request which basically takes a file (multipart/data) and expects an answer whenever it has been processed. (Time taken will be reflected in the size of the file), but potentially minutes.

On our production/test servers we have an nginx proxy which gives a 504 (Gateway Time-out) after 60 seconds.

Is it possible/how to code it in such a way that it won't throw this error after 60 seconds?

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", url, true);

oReq.onload = function() {
        if(oReq.status == 200) {
          // Sucess
        }
}
oReq.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("form-data")));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
              // Sucess
            }
    }
    oReq.open("POST", url, true);
    oReq.send(new FormData(document.getElementById("form-data")));
```

Comment: @MichaelBui, honestly, i cant. i dont have much of experience with javascript. i just think that will work. i just tested similar request in my application and it waiting 10 min for now. and no 504

Comment: Still doesn't solve my issue with the nginx proxy giving 504 after 60 seconds.